# shell endless loop for find command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find, variable

I was working on a shell script where I came across this problem that I couldn't solve

The following command is supposed to find all shell files in `/`.

```
PATHS_SHELL=$(sudo find / -name '*.sh')
```

If I execute the command without assigning it to a variable, it works just fine.
But when I assign it to `PATHS_SHELL`. It gives me an endless loop with the following text

```
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 27: seq: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 159: sleep: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 27: seq: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 108: sleep: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 27: seq: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 124: sleep: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 27: seq: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 134: sleep: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 138: systemctl: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 27: seq: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 146: sleep: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 149: ps: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 149: grep: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 149: wc: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 150: [: : integer expression expected
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 27: seq: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 27: seq: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 159: sleep: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 27: seq: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 108: sleep: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 27: seq: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 124: sleep: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 27: seq: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 134: sleep: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 138: systemctl: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 27: seq: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 146: sleep: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 149: ps: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 149: grep: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 149: wc: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 150: [: : integer expression expected
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 27: seq: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 27: seq: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 159: sleep: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 27: seq: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 108: sleep: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 27: seq: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 124: sleep: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 27: seq: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 134: sleep: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 138: systemctl: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 27: seq: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 146: sleep: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 149: ps: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 149: wc: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 149: grep: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 150: [: : integer expression expected
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 27: seq: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 27: seq: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 159: sleep: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 27: seq: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 108: sleep: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 27: seq: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 124: sleep: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 27: seq: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 134: sleep: command not found
/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh: line 138: systemctl: command not found
```

Before this endless output, the output is many of the shell file paths which is the expected and correct output. e.g.

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-48/tools/testing/selftests/netfilter/ipvs.sh
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-48/tools/testing/selftests/netfilter/ipip-conntrack-mtu.sh
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-48/tools/testing/selftests/netfilter/conntrack_tcp_unreplied.sh
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-48/tools/testing/selftests/netfilter/nft_fib.sh
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-48/tools/testing/selftests/netfilter/nft_nat_zones.sh
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-48/tools/testing/selftests/netfilter/nft_meta.sh
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-48/tools/testing/selftests/netfilter/nft_zones_many.sh
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-48/tools/testing/selftests/netfilter/nft_concat_range.sh
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-48/tools/testing/selftests/netfilter/nf_nat_edemux.sh
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-48/tools/testing/selftests/netfilter/nft_nat.sh
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-48/tools/testing/selftests/netfilter/conntrack_icmp_related.sh
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-48/tools/testing/selftests/livepatch/test-shadow-vars.sh
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-48/tools/testing/selftests/livepatch/test-livepatch.sh
```

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the actual script you are using. The errors cannot be produced by the command you show, they refer to lines 27, 134 and 138 of  `/home/kibnakamoto/workspace/Astrobee/scripts/daemon/astrobee/status_leds.sh`. I am guessing that you are later _using_ the variable, most probably using it without quoting it correctly, and that produces the errors, but we can't help without seeing the rest of the script or, even better, a small part of the script that we can run to reproduce the errors.

Comment: Possibly you meant `readarray -td '' sh_scripts < <(sudo find / -name '*.sh' -type f -print0)` to assign the list of the paths of regular files with names ending in `.sh` to a variable. `PATHS_SHELL=$(sudo find / -name '*.sh')` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Or you've used `$PATH` as a variable to index into `$PATHS_SHELL`?

Comment: @roaima, that was the problem, the endless loop was from a ```cat x y >> x```. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you used the reserved variable `$PATH` to index across your string `$PATHS_SHELL`. This variable holds the list of directories to be searched for commands, so when you overwrote it, none of your scripted commands could be found anymore. Hence the errors about commands not being found.